# Display a 2D grid of images or shapes in java

Tags: java, javafx, multidimensional-array, grid

I made a 2D grid of ASCII characters before in which i was able to move an ascii character around. Now i want to take it to the next level by making a "visualised" version of it in a javafx window. I have tried making 2 image objects, one with a black square inside of it, and one with a white one and then putting those 2 objects multiple times inside a 2D grid like this:

```
  Image[][] Grid = {
  {B,W,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B},
  {B,B,B,B,W,W,W,B,B,B,B},
  {B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B}
  };
```

The problem is that the only way i know how to display them, is by making an imageview object for each index and if i were to say, want a 25X25 grid, that would mean i would have to make 625 imageview objects which would obviously be ridiculous.

I also tried simply putting the grid indexes one by one into the pane like this:

```
HBox gameLayout = new HBox(Grid[1][1], Grid[1][2], Grid[1][3]);
```

but that gives me a "invocationTargetException".

My goal is to be able to make snake by specifically targeting and manipulating grid elements. I want the square-color/imageView/rectangle/whatever to change when i change the value of a "B"array element to "W" (white) but the things i'v tried are either very inefficient or just don't work.

Comment: The `InvocationTargetException` usually holds key information deeper than typical within its stacktrace, and you would do well to seek this information out

Comment: Note that different `ImageView`s can reference the same `Image`, so your naïve approach may not be as ridiculous as you think.

Comment: You could also use something from [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html).

Comment: @James_D I am confused about your point. As you can see in the grid, i am using the same images (B and W) lots of times. The problem is that in order to display each and every grid element, i have to "print" each one of them out individually by making a single imageView object for every index, which does seem ridiculous to me.

Comment: What seems ridiculous about it?

Comment: @Sedrick Yes, i thought about that too. I tried using a rectangle but failed because: 1. Just like with the images, i can't put the grid indexes directly into the HBox due to the exception error, and 2. unlike images, there is no "rectangleView" that could fix this in some way for me.

Comment: You could also just use `Region`s, with backgrounds set on them. It's hard to understand what your objection is to anything you (or others) have suggested. Also, you keep mentioning an exception without actually telling us what the cause of the exception is.

Comment: Well, your problem seems to be that you are adding `Images` to the `HBox` instead of `ImageViews`.

Comment: When people normally do `Grid` related stuff, they use a `GridPane`, `TilePane` or some similar `Node`.

Comment: @James_D It seems ridiculous to me because that would mean that i would have to write ImageView example = new ImageView(Grid[example][example]); 625 times, or am i just stupid and is there a faster way? Regarding your second comment, i'll try to find out more about your suggested technique and the cause of the exception.

Comment: You know that Java has things called "loops", right?

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear what your objection is to creating multiple `ImageView`s. Since they can refer to the same `Image` instance, this should be fairly efficient (the image data doesn't need to be replicated).

This seems to work just fine:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TiledBoard extends Application {

    private final int tileSize = 30 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image b = createImage(Color.BLACK);
        Image w = createImage(Color.WHITE);


        Image[][] grid = {
            {b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b},
            {b,b,b,b,w,w,w,b,b,b,b},
            {b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b}
        };

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        // for visualizing the different squares:
        gridPane.setHgap(2);
        gridPane.setVgap(2);
        gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");

        for (int y = 0 ; y < grid.length ; y++) {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < grid[y].length ; x++) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(grid[y][x]);
                imageView.setFitWidth(tileSize);
                imageView.setFitHeight(tileSize);
                gridPane.add(imageView, x, y);
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Image createImage(Color color) {
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(1, 1);
        image.getPixelWriter().setColor(0, 0, color);
        return image ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

You could do this with some kind of `Shape` (e.g. `Rectangle`), if you prefer:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Color b = Color.BLACK;
    Color w = Color.WHITE;


    Color[][] grid = {
        {b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b},
        {b,b,b,b,w,w,w,b,b,b,b},
        {b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b}
    };

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    // for visualizing the different squares:
    gridPane.setHgap(2);
    gridPane.setVgap(2);
    gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");

    for (int y = 0 ; y < grid.length ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < grid[y].length ; x++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(tileSize, tileSize, grid[y][x]);
            gridPane.add(rect, x, y);
        }
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

or with a `Region`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Color b = Color.BLACK;
    Color w = Color.WHITE;


    Color[][] grid = {
        {b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b},
        {b,b,b,b,w,w,w,b,b,b,b},
        {b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b}
    };

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    // for visualizing the different squares:
    gridPane.setHgap(2);
    gridPane.setVgap(2);
    gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");

    for (int y = 0 ; y < grid.length ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < grid[y].length ; x++) {
            Region rect = new Region();
            rect.setMinSize(tileSize, tileSize);
            rect.setPrefSize(tileSize, tileSize);
            rect.setMaxSize(tileSize, tileSize);
            rect.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(grid[y][x], CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            gridPane.add(rect, x, y);
        }
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Which of these is better really just depends on what else you want to do with them.